# ASP.NET Core update/create dropdown list with jQuery Ajax without manual looping (controller return list of selectlist)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dropdown

Already checked some posts but couldn't find this specific case; jQuery Ajax calls controller method within success and controller returns `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` list. Now question is how an existing dropdown list in view can be re populated with returned list from jQuery Ajax without manually iterating list and create/adding option value attributes.

Something like

```
$("dropdown").options = returnedList
```

like object oriented way. Is this possible at all? Thanks

Comment: No, that's not possible using jQuery alone. Angular, yes, jQuery, no. You would need to manually loop and create the elements before updating the DOM. You can use an implicit loop to make this a one-liner though - check out Array.map()

Comment: Btw, just a side note; i tested manual way without converting selectlist to json and it worked. So if you already have code that returns select list you can use it directly in jquery ajax. All the online info seem to show json data.

Comment: That's true - if you return HTML from your server endpoint then you can just dump that in to the DOM in a single action. However I'd argue this is not good practice as it violates the Separation of Concerns principle. The server should return a generic data structure, such as JSON, which the front-end code then interprets and builds the UI itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Now question is how an existing dropdown list in view can be re populated with returned list from jQuery Ajax without manually iterating list and create/adding option value attributes.

You can try to implement an endpoint that return a partial view result, then you can consume that endpoint from ajax frontend and dynamically append returned dropdown html markup in target container, like below.

```
[HttpGet("DDLPartial")]
public IActionResult GenerateDDL()
{
    List<SelectListItem> Countries = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "MX", Text = "Mexico" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "CA", Text = "Canada" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "US", Text = "USA"  },
    };

    return PartialView("_DdlGenerator", Countries);
}
```

_DdlGenerator.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

<select name="Country" asp-items="Model"></select>
```

On ajax frontend

```
success: function (res) {
    $("#ddl_container").append(res);
}
```